# The method done(ParseObject, ParseException) from the type new FindCallback<ParseUser>(){} is never used locally

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

Below is the error that I am getting:

```
The method done(ParseObject, ParseException) from the type new FindCallback<ParseUser>(){} is never used locally
```

from the line

```
public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {
```

I am not sure if this section of the code was wrongly placed in the code, but I have added multiple log messages and then I realized that it skips this entire section of the code. Below is the section:

```
 public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {

    Log.d(Constants.LOG, "pardeobject");

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (object != null) {
        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "object != null");


        ParseFile file = (ParseFile)object.get("ProfilePicture");
        file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {


        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                //use this bitmap as you want
                ImageView profileimage =(ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);
                // Set the Bitmap into the
                // ImageView
                profileimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Log.d(Constants.LOG, "works");


            } else {
              // something went wrong
                Log.d(Constants.LOG, "error else");

            }
          }
        });

    } else {
      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
        Log.e("Error 2", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
  }
});
}
```

Below is the complete code

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public interface Constants {
          String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
        } 

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);


        return view;
    }

private void setConversationsList() {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>(); 

    // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
    query.setLimit(1);
    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
    //query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
    //query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
    query.orderByDescending("Name");

    Log.d(Constants.LOG, "after query criteria set");



    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {


public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {

            Log.d(Constants.LOG, "pardeobject");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
          public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (object != null) {
                Log.d(Constants.LOG, "object != null");


                ParseFile file = (ParseFile)object.get("ProfilePicture");
                file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {


                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                        //use this bitmap as you want
                        ImageView profileimage =(ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);
                        // Set the Bitmap into the
                        // ImageView
                        profileimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "works");


                    } else {
                      // something went wrong
                        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "error else");

                    }
                  }
                });

            } else {
              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
                Log.e("Error 2", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
          }
        });
        }

        public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistname, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userlistname.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userlistname.get(i).get("Name").toString());








                    //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                }




                usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistname);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                        openConversation(names, i);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}






public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error finding that user",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Update

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {


        public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {
            Log.d(Constants.LOG, "pardeobject");

        ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


        ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

         // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
         // data.
         imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
         imageView.setParseFile(image);
         imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
           @Override
           public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
             Log.i("ParseImageView",
                 "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
           }
         });
        }
```

Update

I am having issue troubleshooting the below:
object cannot be resolved

[image]

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public interface Constants {
        String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
    }

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<String> age;
    private ArrayList<String> headline;
    private ArrayList<String> activityname;

    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber(
            "Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString(
            "Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,
                false);

        return view;
    }

    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        age = new ArrayList<String>();
        headline = new ArrayList<String>();
        activityname = new ArrayList<String>();

        alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>();

        // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query.orderByDescending("Name");

        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryo = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");

        queryo.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        queryo.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        queryo.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        queryo.setLimit(1);
        queryo.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        queryo.orderByDescending("Name");


        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users,ParseException e) {

            // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


                ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

                 // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
                 // data.
                 imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
                 imageView.setParseFile(image);
                 imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                     Log.i("ParseImageView",
                         "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
                   }


             });
            }
        });

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistname, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistname.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userlistname.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void done1(List<ParseUser> userlistheadline, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistheadline.size(); i++) {
                        headline.add(userlistheadline.get(i).get("Headline")
                                .toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistheadline);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_all,
                            headline);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void done2(List<ParseUser> userlistage, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistage.size(); i++) {
                        age.add(userlistage.get(i).get("Age").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistage);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            age);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void done3(List<ParseUser> userlistactivity, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistactivity.size(); i++) {
                        activityname.add(userlistactivity.get(i)
                                .get("ActivityName").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistactivityname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            activityname);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error finding that user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

as well as the below

```
The method done2(List<ParseUser>, ParseException) from the type new FindCallback<ParseUser>(){} is never used locally
```

Comment: Is the error message coming at runtime, from the compiler, or from some code-coverage tool ?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. that error is coming directly from the code in eclipse, where i just hover my mouse over the yellow underline statement and it prompts me with this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is an anonymous implementation of the `FindCallback` interface, which contain the following signature :

```
public abstract void done(List<T> objects,
                      ParseException e)
```

Your method does not match this signature, so is not used (and can't be used) in your program.

If your code compiles correctly, it also mean that the above method has been defined. Check that you did not mix both methods.

---

Base on your update code, here is what you should write (but this is basic Java. If you don't understand it, I would suggest learning the langage before trying to go further. Here is a tutorial that you must read and understand : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> users,ParseException e) {

    // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
    // ...

    }
```

By the way, an important note is that you won't be allowed to manipulate UI objects (like your ParseImageView R.id.profilePictureResult directly in this method, because this must be done in the UI Thread. So you must use the Handler for this. This is a separate problem than the one you submitted here, but this will be your next one. When you are there, just read https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I remove this line         public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {
 than I get the following error Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead for the line      query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

Comment: @user3907211 You need to change the line as described here, not remove it completely.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. WHen I do that it prompts me with two errors: one above - The type new FindCallback(){} must be an abstract class to define abstract methods and the second one at that line Abstract methods do not specify a body i reword it to         public abstract void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {

Comment: the problem is that i cannot specify a body to abstract methods, in which i need to refer to the body, so i am not sure how i would work around this code.

Comment: I have decided to use ParseImageView instead based around this tutorial https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseImageView.html, but still cant managed to get it displayed. I have added an update in my initial post under the update section

Comment: Of course you can't just remove the line ! You must change the signature of the method. I'm pretty sure that the may error shown in Eclipse is that the missing method is not implemented in your anonymous class.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response and clarification. I just encountered a minor issue upon fixing this one. I have updated it under the update section of my initial post. thanks